# Getting Retweet and favorite count from Tweepy stream

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, sttwitterapi, twitterapi-python

I've been using Tweepy to listen to a Twitter stream. For some reason, all the posts have 0 `favorite_count` & `retweet_count`.

Do I have to go after some time and request an update for Tweet IDs?

I would expect to get any update from the stream object. Otherwise, it is very limited, even with the 100 IDs per request, as the rate is very low compared to the tens of thousands I'm getting in the stream.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [the statuses/filter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter), you're getting Tweets in realtime, so they've all just been Tweeted and wouldn't have any favorites/likes or Retweets.

Comment: Is there a way to add (or have) favorite and retweet count to the stream listener?

Comment: Those counts are accurate as 0 because as answered, Tweets that have just been Tweeted don't have any favorites or Retweets.

Comment: I understood that. What I would like is to have real-time updates to tweets by filter keys.

Comment: If you mean you want to track favorites and Retweets through realtime streams by tracking keywords, that's not something Twitter's API supports.

Comment: `statuses/lookup` is my closest option?

Comment: If you have multiple Tweet IDs, that would be the way to get the Status/Tweet objects, yes.